# ggplot2: add line for average count values resulting from geom_freqpoly

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, tidyverse, frequency

I am trying to add an additional line to my geom_freqpoly plot that represents the average count per binwidth. I tried two different things but none of them were successful.

1. I tried adding the line as a geom_line but got an error asking if I map my stat in the wrong layer.

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = ..count..)) +
  geom_freqpoly(aes(color = Species), 
                binwidth = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(yintercept = "mean"))
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: yintercept
#> Error: Aesthetics must be valid computed stats. Problematic aesthetic(s): y = ..count... 
#> Did you map your stat in the wrong layer?
```

2. I tried adding another geom_freqpoly, like:

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_freqpoly(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = ..count.., color = Species), 
                binwidth = 0.2) +
  geom_freqpoly(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = mean(..count..), color = "red"), binwidth = 0.2)
```

But the resulting line is not what I expect.

[image: Image wrong result]

Using the Iris dataset I would expect that the new line would represent the average count of Species by the defined binwidth (see image below), not what I am getting. My understanding is that geom_freqpoly divides a continues variable (like Petal.Length) in length bins (of 0.2 length in this case). So for each bin I want to have the average count of each specie and draw a line connecting those points.

[image: Drawing Expected result]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the edit of your question maybe this is what you expected.

The problem with your approach is that `mean(..count..)` simply computes the mean of the vector `..count..` which gives you one number and therefore a horizontal line. Therefore simply divide by the number of `groups` or `Species`

I'm not completely satisfied with my solution because I would like to avoid the code `n_distinct(iris$Species)`. I tried some approaches with `tapply` but failed. So as a first step ...

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_freqpoly(aes(color = Species), binwidth = .2) +
  geom_freqpoly(aes(y = ..count.. / n_distinct(iris$Species)), color = "red", binwidth = .2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much!! That's what I needed. And thanks for the explanation I appreciate it!